# PSQL Exception when trying to .createStatement() on a connection

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I wanted to make a result set but calling .createStatement() on the connection returns a PSQL Exception.

```
ResultSet resultSet = PostgresConnection
                     .getInstance()
                     .createStatement()
                     .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM musicians"); // error
```

I noticed that .isClosed() returns true, I am new to databases does that mean that the database closes and I am calling a method on a closed connection?

How can I fix this?

**PostgresConnection**

```java
package utils;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PostgresConnection {
    private static final PostgresConnection instance = new PostgresConnection();
    private Connection connection;

    private PostgresConnection () {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dropify",
                "postgres",
                "sony")) {
            this.connection = connection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failure.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Connection getInstance () {
        return instance.connection;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(PostgresConnection.getInstance().isClosed());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            PostgresConnection.getInstance().createStatement(); //error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```java
true
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:712)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.createStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:228)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.createStatement(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:189)
    at com.sampleApps.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: try catch is closing your connection.
It's try catch with resources so after executing lines inside try it closes the connection. Try to execute your statement inside try catch block. Or dont use try catch with resources.

Comment: Doing database connection management properly is _hard_. Storing a `Connection` instance in a singleton may be appropriate for educational purposes, but it will be problematic in the long term. There are lots of excellent open-source connection pool implementations for Java, the use of which will mitigate a lot of the nasties.

Comment: @Szprota21 thanks! Fixed it.
Also Kevin, I will keep that in mind :)